# Where to run gcloud init?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, command-line-interface, gcloud

Need to access some gcloud functions in a react project. Should I run gcloud init in the project root folder or within the firebase functions/ folder? Will it interfere with firebase deploy for the functions?

Following this: https://medium.com/@nedavniat/how-to-perform-and-schedule-firestore-backups-with-google-cloud-platform-and-nodejs-be44bbcd64ae

I already have some other firebase functions set up which I would deploy with firebase deploy --only functions. When I got to step 5 of the above tutorial, I got a gcloud command not found. I followed the instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/#install_the_latest_cloud_tools_version_cloudsdk_current_version
 and when it got to step 5 in that, I presume I should be doing it somewhere in the project folder to use that project's specific login? Without running it I get the following error when trying to use:

```
gcloud functions deploy backup --runtime nodejs8 --trigger-topic YOUR_TOPIC_NAME_HERE
```

> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) Error parsing [name].
>   The [function] resource is not properly specified.
>   Failed to find attribute [project]. The attribute can be set in the following ways: 
>   - provide the argument [--project] on the command line
>   - set the property [core/project]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here. What exactly do you mean when you say you need to "access some gcloud functions"?

Comment: See edited question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is clear. Add `--project <project id>` at the deploy command or perform a `gcloud config set project <project id>`.

If you use only firebase, firebase has automatically create a GCP project. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com to view your project name or ID. I think it's also possible to view this information in firebase console.

Comment: Thank you-- should it be run in the project root directory or within the functions/ folder?

Comment: Run it where you want in your console. The params are kept in gcloud CLI config

Comment: Got it-- thank you. Because she had mentioned in the tutorial to make sure I was in the functions folder when running the deploy function, wasn't sure if I had to be somewhere specific for the init.

Comment: The `gcloud init` is a config command and can be ran anywhere. But, some command for deployment (AppEngine, Function, CloudRun,...) required to be launched in the correct folder